# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, windows-10

I'm having trouble connecting to an oracle database
Windows 10 [OpenServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL3QY.jpg) php-7.3 version
[php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVlpi.jpg) file

```
;extension = memcached
;extension = mongodb
extension  = mysqli
extension = oci8_12c
extension  = odbc
extension  = openssl
;extension = pdflib
```

laravel composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-oci8": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.5",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^4.2",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.15",
    "yajra/laravel-oci8": "8"
},
```

*composer update* [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waxci.jpg)

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
   - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-oci8 * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's oci8 extension.
Problem 2
   - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-oci8 8 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-oci8[v8.0.0].
   - yajra/laravel-oci8 v8.0.0 requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's oci8 extension.
```

Comment: Please add any relevant code as text. Do not link images.